# Shuffle product of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I want to do the following: I have two lists `{a_1,...a_n}, {b_1,...,b_n}` and I would like to build now all shuffles out of this. This means all unions of these lists while still keeping the individual order of the parent lists.

Example

```
{a,b}, {c,d}
```

> {{c,d,a,b},{c,a,d,b},{c,a,b,d},{a,c,d,b},{a,c,b,d},{a,b,c,d}}

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: A friendly helper, I'm glad you like my answer, but I always recommend waiting 24 hours before Accepting an answer, to let everyone around the world have a chance to reply.  You may like other answers better if you give them a chance to happen. :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll wait :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Recursion

This is top-level code and therefore unlikely to be as efficient as a compiled solution, but the recursive algorithm should have reasonable computational complexity:

```
f[u : {a_, x___}, v : {b_, y___}, c___] := f[{x}, v, c, a] ~Join~ f[u, {y}, c, b]

f[{x___}, {y___}, c___] := {{c, x, y}}  (* rule for empty-set termination *)
```

Now:

```
f[{a, b}, {c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, d, a, b}}
> ```

#### Proof of result

A question was raised regarding the validity of the result of this function.  You can graphically demonstrate that this function yields the correct result (as I understand it) for length 2,4 lists with this:

```
ArrayPlot @ f[{Pink, Red}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

- Pink always precedes Red
- The gray values are always in order
- No shuffles are missing
- No shuffles are duplicated

I must conclude that the referenced paper is in error, or the original question diverges from the definition of "shuffle product" therein.

---

### Extension to multiple lists

While it is possible to extend a two-list shuffle product to multiple lists using `Fold` it may be of interest to do it directly.  *This code is slow however and should not be used where performance matters.*

```
f2[in_, out___] :=
 Join @@ ReplaceList[in, {x___, {a_, b___}, y___} :> f2[{x, {b}, y}, out, a]]

f2[{{} ..}, out__] := {{out}}

f2[{{1, 2}, {Cyan}, {LightRed, Pink, Red}}] // Transpose // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

---

### Alternative method

***Edit:*** I had a function `g` which used `Permutations` on a binary list to generate all the base orderings, but I did not fill these orderings efficiently.  [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) used the same start but came up with a clever and fast way to fill those orderings.  I am replacing this section of my answer with a refactored version of his code; credit to him for making the `Permutations` approach competitive.  (If you are interested in my original, slow `g` see the edit history.)

Here is a refactoring of rasher's `shufflem` function; I shall call mine `shuffleW`.

***Edit 2017***: Now significantly faster after moving or eliminating several Transpose operations.

```
shuffleW[s1_, s2_] := 
  Module[{p, tp, ord},
    p = Permutations @ Join[1 & /@ s1, 0 & /@ s2]\[Transpose];
    tp = BitXor[p, 1];
    ord = Accumulate[p] p + (Accumulate[tp] + Length[s1]) tp;
    Outer[Part, {Join[s1, s2]}, ord, 1][[1]]\[Transpose]
  ]

shuffleW[{a, b}, {c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, d, a, b}}
> ```

---

### Timings

Timings of these functions as well as Simon's `shuffles` and rasher's `shufflem`, performed in v10.1.

I am also including rasher's unnamed but very fast penultimate `Ordering` method.  I shall call it `shuffleO` and format it for readability.

```
shuffleO[s1_, s2_] :=
  With[{all = Join[s1, s2]},
    Join[1 & /@ s1, 0 & /@ s2]
      // Permutations
      // Map[Ordering @ Ordering @ # &]
      // Flatten
      // all[[#]] &
      // Partition[#, Length[all]] &
  ]

s1 = CharacterRange["a", "k"];
s2 = Range @ 11;

f[s1, s2]        // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffles[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shufflem[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffleO[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffleW[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {2.6523, 705432}
>
> {2.0618, 705432}
>
> {1.455, 705432}
>
> {0.78, 705432}
>
> {0.759, 705432}
> ```

rasher's methods are the fastest in this test.
I find my `f` the most readable as the mechanism of its action is directly visible.  Take your pick. :-)

#### Disparate list lengths

[Yi Wang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7253/yi-wang) posted a nice clean method that has some interesting properties.  Specifically it is the best performing solution so far in the case of input lists of significantly disparate length, but they must be fed in the correct order or the performance is magnitudes worse.  First in the symmetric test above:

```
Fold[insertElem, {{s2, 0}}, s1][[All, 1]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {2.67, 705432}
> ```

Now with disparate lists:

```
s1 = Range[80];
s2 = {"a", "b", "c"};

Fold[insertElem, {{s2, 0}}, s1][[All, 1]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {6.25, 91881}
> ```

Swap the lists and try again (so that `insertElem` is Folded over the shorter list):

```
{s2, s1} = {s1, s2};

Fold[insertElem, {{s2, 0}}, s1][[All, 1]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.121, 91881}
> ```

This is significantly faster than all the others (order makes little difference to these):

```
f[s1, s2]        // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffles[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shufflem[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffleO[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
shuffleW[s1, s2] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.529, 91881}
>
> {0.5637, 91881}
>
> {0.562, 91881}
>
> {0.4135, 91881}
>
> {0.4356, 91881}
> ```

Comment: Very nice, that's what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Curious what my real entry does in your environment...

Comment: @rasher That looks very interesting. I'm working on another post but I'll run timings a bit later. (If I forget, poke me.)  I see yours is also based on `Permutations` of a binary list; I was not happy with the way I filled in those values.  I hope you worked some magic! :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, I scratched my beard for a bit on that! I'm sure there's still something left in it, was pleased with initial results - and of course, it extends to more than two lists *fairly* easily, I think. Look forward to your results!

Comment: I picked this one, since - as Mr. Wizard stated and I agree - the mechanism of its action is directly visible. I don't need performance at this moment so much :)

Comment: @Afriendlyhelper Thanks (again) for the Accept.  I'm sure waiting was worth it however, as now you also have a method that is twice as fast should you need it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for taking the time. Will add explanation to my OP (after I grab another cigar ;->). Also, meant to say in first comment, your first result is a thing of beauty - I Just read it this AM (I like to try my hand before reading the experts...).

Comment: @Afriendlyhelper: I'd pick the same, and thanks for a most interesting puzzle!

Comment: @rasher Thanks for the kind words.  By the way, you are proving to be quite an asset to this site.  Glad to have you here. :-)

Comment: I prefer your method too :-)

Comment: @Simon Thank you.  You know I value your opinion.  I do think `f` is a nice showcase of *Mathematica* pattern syntax.  (I'd hate to write that in Visual Basic. lol)

Comment: On my system your refactoring of rasher's code is faster than his original, but I find that my Flatten & Partition suggestion is faster than Outer.

Comment: Also, your code multiplies by `tp` twice, It's (a tiny bit) faster to take the `Times` out of `accf` and use `accf[p] p` in `ord`

Comment: @Simon Good point.  I'll try another refactor tomorrow, if I haven't moved on to something else, or if someone hasn't posted an even faster method by then. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Check out the new method in my post using the all-powerful, under-appreciated `Ordering`. I was surprised at its speed.

Comment: @rasher `Ordering` is not under-appreciated by me but I simply didn't think to use it here.  How fast is that code on your system?  In v7 it is slower than any of the `shuffle*` functions but a bit faster than `f`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, as I said in comment, faster than I thought it would be, but not a hot-rod, about 30% slower than the R/W/S shufflers, though it strangely varies with certain list lengths. I just thought it an amusing use of `Ordering`.

Comment: @rasher It's actually a very good use of ordering and I'm a bit annoyed I didn't even think to test it here.

Comment: I think I found a bug or something. Suppose I want to shuffle {0,1} and {0,0,1,1}. It should give (010011) + 3(001011) + 9(000111) + (001101) but instead it gives 9 {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1} + 4 {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1} + 
 {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1} + {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}

Comment: @Afriendlyhelper Let me look at that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard> fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Afriendlyhelper I cannot tell from your statement why you believe the "it should give" output is correct.  Would you please edit your question to describe that?

Comment: I was looking at a Mathematicians thesis about Multiple Zeta Values and he states the shuffle of the sets {0,1} and {0,0,1,1} mentioned above and the result. See page 11 here http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/GdT/The%20Algebra%20Of%20Multiple%20Zeta%20Values.pdf Then I wanted to reproduce this by hand and code and found disagreement between the two :(

Comment: @Afriendlyhelper Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: my apologies - there's indeed an error in the paper :( Let's blame it on my lack of sleep for not seeing it... Thanks!

Comment: Love the shuffleW, it was super-frustrating (in a good way) to think of the same solution while driving home and then to realize that you implemented it. Wonder if compiling can accelerate parts of it.

Answer (score 15):

Probably not too bad performance-wise, haven't tested though:

```
x = {a, b};
y = {c, d};

n = Length[x] + Length[y];
px = Subsets[Range[n], {Length[x]}];
py = Reverse[Subsets[Range[n], {Length[y]}]];

Normal /@ MapThread[SparseArray[{#1 -> x, #2 -> y}] &, {px, py}]

(* {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, d, a, b}} *)
```

**Update**

This has better performance:

```
shuffles[x_, y_] := Module[{n, px, py, z, xy},
    n = Length /@ {x, y};
    {px, py} = Subsets[Range @ Tr @ n, {#}] & /@ n;
    py = Reverse @ py;
    xy = z = Join[x, y];
    (z[[#]] = xy; z) & /@ Join[px, py, 2]
  ]

shuffles[{a, b}, {c, d}]
(* {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, d, a, b}} *)
```

**Tweaking other people's code**

This is a refactoring of Mr Wizard's refactoring of rasher's code. The primary changes are to `Flatten` the ordering matrix so that the whole output is extracted with a single `Part` call (and subsequently partitioned), and to reduce the number of `Transpose` operations. On my PC this gives about a 30% speed gain over Mr Wizard's version:

```
shuffleSWR[s1_, s2_] := Module[{p, tp, accf, ord, ss},
  p = Transpose @ Permutations @ Join[1 & /@ s1, 0 & /@ s2];
  tp = BitXor[p, 1];
  ord = Accumulate[p] p + (Accumulate[tp] + Length[s1]) tp;
  ss = Join[s1, s2];
  ss[[Flatten @ Transpose @ ord]] ~Partition~ Length[ss]]
```

Comment: I refactored `shuffles`.  If you don't like the changes just revert it.

Answer (score 14):

Something different, impractical yet amusing, with a hint of mathematical insouciance...

```
s1 = {a, b, c}
s2 = {f, g, h}

sall = Join[s1, s2];
ln = Length[sall];

s = Solve[
   Max[sall] == ln && Min[sall] == 1 && Less[Sequence @@ s1] && 
    Less[Sequence @@ s2] && Unequal[Sequence @@ sall], sall, Integers];

Range@ln /. MapAt[Reverse, s, {All, All}]
```

And, for my actual entry into the horse race, I offer the following. Seems to beat the current record holder pretty handily in my limited tests.

```
shufflem[s1_, s2_] := Module[{ss, sr, s1l, s2l, p, pp, tp, pres},

  {ss, sr} = {Join[s1, s2], Range@((s1l = Length@s1) + (s2l = Length@s2))};

  p = Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1, s1l], ConstantArray[0, s2l]]];

  pp = (Accumulate@Transpose[p] // Transpose) p;

  tp = Clip[p, {1, 0}, {1, 0}];

  pres = pp + 
    Clip[(Accumulate@Transpose[tp] // Transpose) tp + s1l, {s1l + 1, Max[sr]}, {0, 0}];

  ss[[#]] & /@ pres
  ]
```

As requested by Mr. Wizard, an explanation for readers.

Pondering this over dinner, I imagined it as one list "bubbling" through the other. The pattern that
came to mind was obvious: a binary counter kind of thing, where the 1 and 0 represent positions in the
shuffled list.

Having distinct values makes the permutation operation reasonable, i.e., just naively permuting
the whole "deck" of the lists and the filtering results in mostly wasted work, since most will have elements violating the order rule, while having only representations of *some* element in *some* list means we'll never see such
transpositions in the permutation.

With that in mind, I build a list of possible positions in the shuffled list (the range of total length in sr), along with
making a joined version of the lists (ss).

I then build (in p) a list with 1 and 0, in quantities matching the lengths of each original list, and generate the permutations. So now I have a big list of all possible permutations of the final shuffled list, with 1's where an element from the first list goes, and a 0 for those from the second.

We want the elements to fill these 1/0 slots to be in the order of the originals, that is, element 1,2,3... for each.

So I accumulate over each permutation (I double transpose for performance), leaving me with say something like
{1,0,1,1,0,0} going to {1,1,2,3,3,3}. I'm only interested in the items from the first list on the first pass, so 
I multiply the accumulants by their respective permutation, e.g., in the current example we'd get {1,0,2,3,0,0} for that one permutation, meaning from the first list, slots 1,3, and 4 get filled from the list elements 1,2 and 3 of the 
joined list.

The second pass fills the 0 spots from the second list, by doing the same thing with some hand-waving to get the values into the second half of the joined list: I clip the permutations to turn 1->0 and 0->1, do the same machination as the last, but I *add* an offset (the length of the first list prefix in the joined list). I clip out noise values, ending up with the list of permutations with elements looking like {1,4,2,3,5,6}, etc.

Finally, I map over that result of permutation lists indexing them into the joined list, so for example, if the joined
list were {a,b,c,d,e,f}, the example permutation element would result in {a,d,b,c,e,f} being pulled.

Vectorizing the work makes it snappy - the *vast* majority of the time overall is in mapping over the work to get the final result.

Lastly, a surprisingly quick (I thought it would be much slower than it turns out to be) method that avoids any mathematical manipulation:

```
Module[{jl = Flatten[{#1, #2}]},
   Partition[
    jl[[Flatten[
       Ordering /@ 
        Ordering /@ 
         Permutations[
          Join[ConstantArray[1, Length[#1]], 
           ConstantArray[0, Length[#2]]]]]]], Length[jl]]] &[s1, s2]
```

And this use of ordering is even faster due to the relatively small size of input lists, turns out mapping over them is quicker, resulting in overall time that seems competitive with the refactored*refactored version of my original. Interesting:

```
Partition[ Join[#1, #2][[Flatten[ Ordering[Ordering[#]] & /@ 
       Permutations[Flatten[{1 & /@ #1, 0 & /@ #2}]]]]],
   Length[#1] + Length[#2]] &[s1, s2]
```

Finally, the above generalized to allow more lists (timings on a netbook that was near bursting into flames):

```
lists = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l, m, n, o}}

res2 = Partition[ Flatten[##][[Flatten[ Ordering[Ordering[#]] & /@ 
          Permutations[Flatten[MapIndexed[(idx = #2[[1]]; idx & /@ #1) &, ##]]]]]],
      Length[Flatten[##]]] &[lists]; // Timing

Length[res2]

res2 // Short

(* {4.539629, Null} *)

(* 630630 *)

(* {{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o},{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,i,k,l,m,n,o},<<630627>>,{j,k,l,m,n,o,e,f,g,h,i,a,b,c,d}} *)
```

Any of the methods become pretty useless with large lists and/or large number of lists:

[image]

e.g, two lists of 40 elements, were one able to generate permutations that adhere to the ordering rule at a rate of 1,000,0000 per second would far exceed the age of the universe before completing.

The following generates a random permutation that adheres to the ordering rules for such cases:

```
randomOrderedShuffle[lists__] := 
 Join[lists][[Ordering@Ordering@RandomSample@(Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ 
         Transpose[{Range@Length@{lists}, Length /@ {lists}}])]]

(* The following example has 3,644,153,415,887,633,116,359,073,848,179,365,185,734,400  "valid" permutations... *)

randomOrderedShuffle[Range[10], Range[11, 20], Range[21, 30], Range[31, 40], Range[41, 50], Range[51, 60]] // Timing

(*  {0., {1, 21, 41, 11, 22, 12, 31, 23, 51, 2, 3, 52, 42, 13, 14, 53, 43, 15, 32, 4, 54, 16, 33, 17, 34, 55, 5, 44, 45, 56, 6, 35, 57, 36, 7, 46, 8, 37, 58, 24, 59, 47, 25, 9, 10, 60, 26, 48, 18, 27, 19, 38, 49, 28, 39, 29, 40, 30, 20, 50}}  *)
```

Comment: :) ... it does only work with unassigned variables, though.

Comment: Yes, it was meant as a goof. Adding my *real* entry now...

Comment: This is the approach I wanted to take, but I couldn't see a fast way to compute `pres`. The `Accumulate` trick is very clever. Excellent work!

Comment: @SimonWoods: Appreciate the comment! Yes, as I commented to Mr.W, I was scratching around for a bit on that. I think there's more tweaking ;-)

Comment: Regarding the last point, that the `Map` is the slowest part, you can save some time by doing `ss[[Flatten@pres]] ~Partition~ Length[ss]` instead

Comment: @SimonWoods On my system it appears that my use of `Outer` is equivalently fast; can you confirm that for later versions?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Along the lines of what I am/was tweaking. Have some other ideas, but cigar is at lip-burning stage, time to hit the sack. I'm curious what morning shall bring ;-). What a great question and set of answers!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Curious what last edit does in your tests: seems as fast as fastest refactoring of accumulation method in my limited tests, and prettier IMO...

Comment: @rasher Your latest non-generalized code takes 2 seconds in v7 on my symmetric test.  Nevertheless I like it very much.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks much for taking the time to test in your environment!

Comment: I want to make sure I understand one of your statements; can you confirm that in v9 the second line is faster than the first?: `Ordering /@ Ordering /@ Permutations[Range@9] // Timing // First` versus `Ordering[Ordering[#]] & /@ Permutations[Range@9] // Timing // First`.  In v7 they are equivalent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: yes, on my toy testing, second is consistently 10-20% faster. Also, in my tests, the non-generalized version of the latest is neck-and-neck with the SWR refactoring of my OP. Finally, I'm a bit puzzled by timings on the generalized version - it is consistently 20% slower than the other with same arguments. As if passing `##` instead of referencing the distinct arguments is making a difference. It's a ludicrous hour here, so off to sack, but I'll be poking at this.

Comment: I love seeing you take this "simple" question so far.  I'd vote again if I could.  By the way, in the extreme the recursion (`f`) has an advantage in that each branch can be interrupted and continued as needed, whereas solutions using `Permutations` will eventually run out of memory.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: LOL, I don't have to tell you, it's one of those non-trivial "trivial" questions! Yep, there's a many-fold beauty to your recursive solution - learned much from going over it.

Answer (score 11):

What about inserting the first list into the second list at every allowed position (where allowed means preserving the order of the first list)?

```
lst1 = {a, b};
lst2 = {c, d};

insertElem[lst_, x_] := 
  Join @@ (Table[{Insert[#, x, i], i}, {i, #2 + 1, Length@# + 1}] & @@@ lst)

Fold[insertElem, {{lst2, 0}}, lst1][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, d, a, b}}
> ```

I was told not to use the slow Insert. But here generating permutations is much harder. Thus Insert may not be too bad.

**EDIT: Another worse attempt**

This is not as efficient as the above one. But just for fun, one can generate the positions of lst2 in the result, then generate positions of lst1~Join~lst2 in the result. Finally, permute lst1~Join~lst2 into the final result:

```
comb[lenIn_, lenOut_] := Module[{i},
  i[0] = 0;
  Flatten[#, lenOut - 1] & @ With[{
     elem = i@# & /@ Range@lenOut, 
     ranges = Sequence @@ ({i[#], i[# - 1], lenIn - 1} & /@ Range@lenOut)}, 
    Table[elem, ranges]]]

(* e.g. comb[3,2] gives {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} *)
(* One can also write comb as follows, with even worse performance *)
(* comb[lenIn_, lenOut_] := Select[Tuples[Range[0, lenIn - 1], lenOut], OrderedQ] *)

shufflep[lst1_, lst2_] := Module[{pos2, pos},
  pos2 = Range@Length@lst2 + # & /@ comb[Length@lst1 + 1, Length@lst2];
  pos = Complement[Range[Length@lst1 + Length@lst2], #]~Join~# & /@ pos2;
  Permute[lst1~Join~lst2, InversePermutation@#] & /@ pos]
```

Comment: That is quite a clean method, and I see the possibility to make this code a bit cleaner still.  May I edit your post with these changes?  If you don't like them you can simply "revert" the edit to undo them.

Comment: Sure. You are welcome to edit!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr.Wizard! This is indeed cleaner!

Comment: Notes: (1) If the lists that are assembled are short `Insert` is not expensive; this is a good method.   (2) Because you `Fold` over `lst1`, `lst1` should be the *shorter* of the two lists if there is one; this will be *much* faster than the other way around.

Comment: Please see the timings I added to my answer.  In some cases your method is far and away the fastest method yet posted, when applied correctly.  Well done.

Comment: @YiWang: Very nice. +1

Answer (score 3):

Quite horribly inefficient:

```
l = {{a, b}, {c, d}};

Intersection @@ (Cases[Permutations[Flatten[l]],Riffle[#, ___, {1, -1, 2}]] & /@ l)
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d,  b}, {c, d, a, b}}

... and it only gets worse for the general case with $n$ lists:

```
l = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Intersection @@ (Cases[Permutations[Flatten[l]],Riffle[#, ___, {1, -1, 2}]] & /@ l)
```

> {{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {a, b, c, e, d, f}, {a, b, c, e, f, d}, {a, b, e,
>      c, d, f}, {a, b, e, c, f, d}, {a, b, e, f, c, d}, {a, c, b, d, e, 
>     f}, {a, c, b, e, d, f}, {a, c, b, e, f, d}, {a, c, d, b, e, f}, {a, 
>     c, d, e, b, f}, {a, c, d, e, f, b}, {a, c, e, b, d, f}, {a, c, e, b,
>      f, d}, {a, c, e, d, b, f}, {a, c, e, d, f, b}, {a, c, e, f, b, 
>     d}, {a, c, e, f, d, b}, {a, e, b, c, d, f}, {a, e, b, c, f, d}, {a, 
>     e, b, f, c, d}, {a, e, c, b, d, f}, {a, e, c, b, f, d}, {a, e, c, d,
>      b, f}, {a, e, c, d, f, b}, {a, e, c, f, b, d}, {a, e, c, f, d, 
>     b}, {a, e, f, b, c, d}, {a, e, f, c, b, d}, {a, e, f, c, d, b}, {c, 
>     a, b, d, e, f}, {c, a, b, e, d, f}, {c, a, b, e, f, d}, {c, a, d, b,
>      e, f}, {c, a, d, e, b, f}, {c, a, d, e, f, b}, {c, a, e, b, d, 
>     f}, {c, a, e, b, f, d}, {c, a, e, d, b, f}, {c, a, e, d, f, b}, {c, 
>     a, e, f, b, d}, {c, a, e, f, d, b}, {c, d, a, b, e, f}, {c, d, a, e,
>      b, f}, {c, d, a, e, f, b}, {c, d, e, a, b, f}, {c, d, e, a, f, 
>     b}, {c, d, e, f, a, b}, {c, e, a, b, d, f}, {c, e, a, b, f, d}, {c, 
>     e, a, d, b, f}, {c, e, a, d, f, b}, {c, e, a, f, b, d}, {c, e, a, f,
>      d, b}, {c, e, d, a, b, f}, {c, e, d, a, f, b}, {c, e, d, f, a, 
>     b}, {c, e, f, a, b, d}, {c, e, f, a, d, b}, {c, e, f, d, a, b}, {e, 
>     a, b, c, d, f}, {e, a, b, c, f, d}, {e, a, b, f, c, d}, {e, a, c, b,
>      d, f}, {e, a, c, b, f, d}, {e, a, c, d, b, f}, {e, a, c, d, f, 
>     b}, {e, a, c, f, b, d}, {e, a, c, f, d, b}, {e, a, f, b, c, d}, {e, 
>     a, f, c, b, d}, {e, a, f, c, d, b}, {e, c, a, b, d, f}, {e, c, a, b,
>      f, d}, {e, c, a, d, b, f}, {e, c, a, d, f, b}, {e, c, a, f, b, 
>     d}, {e, c, a, f, d, b}, {e, c, d, a, b, f}, {e, c, d, a, f, b}, {e, 
>     c, d, f, a, b}, {e, c, f, a, b, d}, {e, c, f, a, d, b}, {e, c, f, d,
>      a, b}, {e, f, a, b, c, d}, {e, f, a, c, b, d}, {e, f, a, c, d, 
>     b}, {e, f, c, a, b, d}, {e, f, c, a, d, b}, {e, f, c, d, a, b}}

Comment: @David Relative efficiency may be overrated but computational complexity *is not*.  This fails on the latter.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard O(no!)

Comment: @YvesKlett LOL -- I hope that was written with a smile on your face as I imagine. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard indeed :D

Answer (score 2):

One more way!

```
list1 = {a, b};
list2 = {c, d};
list = Range[2 Length@list1];
first = Select[Permutations[list, {(Length@list1)}], Sort[#] === # &];
second = Complement[list, #] & /@ first;
Normal[SparseArray[#]] & /@
(Join @@@ (Transpose@{Thread[Rule[#, list1]] & /@ first,Thread[Rule[#, list2]] & /@ second}))
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, 
>     b}, {c, d, a, b}}

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to arrive. How about a one-liner using pattern matching:

```
Cases[Cases[Permutations[{a,b,c,d}], {___, a, ___, b, ___}], {___, c, ___, d, ___}]
```

Automated form:

```
MrShuffles[lis1_, lis2_] := Cases[ Cases[Permutations[Join[lis1, lis2]],
 Riffle[lis1, ___, {1, -1, 2}]], Riffle[lis2, ___, {1, -1, 2}]]
```

Example:

```
MrShuffles[{a, b}, {c, d}]
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, 
>     b}, {c, d, a, b}}

```
MrShuffles[{a, b, c}, {d, e}]
```

> {{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, b, d, c, e}, {a, b, d, e, c}, {a, d, b, c, 
>     e}, {a, d, b, e, c}, {a, d, e, b, c}, {d, a, b, c, e}, {d, a, b, e, 
>     c}, {d, a, e, b, c}, {d, e, a, b, c}}

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffle[list1_, list2_] := 
 Module[{i = 0, len1 = Length[list1], len2 = Length[list2]}, 
  Fold[Insert[#1, list2[[Mod[++i, len2, 1]]], #2] &, list1, #] & /@ 
   Subsets[Range[len1 + len2], {len2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well,I'm little blush to see you do this one by one for me,I will edit those image link in future. :)

Comment: I was testing to see that this method works properly.  See my update to http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2113/121 -- you can do the rest.