# Duplicate Permutations with Tuples

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

- **Permutations without repetition**

(in Italian: simple dispositions)

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {3}]
```

or

```
Select[Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}], DuplicateFreeQ]
```

- **Permutations with repetition**

(in Italian: dispositions with repetition)

```
Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]
```

or

```
Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}]
```

- **Combinations without repetition**

(in Italian: simple combinations)

```
DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {3}]]]
```

or

```
DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Select[Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}], DuplicateFreeQ]]]
```

- **Combinations with repetition**

(in Italian: combinations with repetition)

```
DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]]
```

or

```
DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}]]]
```

- **Permutations of n distinct elements**

(in Italian: idem)

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {4}]
```

or

```
Select[Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}], DuplicateFreeQ]
```

- **Permutations of n elements with a element repeating twice**

(in Italian: idem)

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, c}, {4}] =

= {{a, b, c, c}, {a, c, b, c}, {a, c, c, b}, {b, a, c, c}, {b, c, a, c}, {b, c, c, a},
   {c, a, b, c}, {c, a, c, b}, {c, b, a, c}, {c, b, c, a}, {c, c, a, b}, {c, c, b, a}}
```

or

?????????

Can you tell me a way to duplicate this command with the use of "Tuples[*matrix*]"?

Thank you!

Comment: `Select[Tuples[{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, 
     d}}], DuplicateFreeQ] /. d -> c`

Comment: `x = {a, b, c, c}; DeleteDuplicates@Select[Tuples[{x, x, x, x}], Sort[#] == Sort[x] &]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend *not* generating more tuples than you need, then filtering output, as that method "blows up" very easily.

Instead I would draw your attention to the similarity between this problem and a shuffle product:

- [Shuffle product of two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/121)

Using the `f` function from my answer there:

```
f[u : {a_, x___}, v : {b_, y___}, c___] := f[{x}, v, c, a] ~Join~ f[u, {y}, c, b]

f[{x___}, {y___}, c___] := {{c, x, y}}
```

Compare the outputs of:

```
f[{1}, {2, 2, 2}]

Permutations[{1, 2, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1}}
>
> {{1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1}}
> ```

So we can implement a duplicate-aware permutation function using `f` as follows:

```
f2[a_, b_] := Join @@ (f[#, b] & /@ a)

perms[a_List] := Fold[f2, {{}}, Gather[a]]
```

Test:

```
Sort @ perms[{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}] === Sort @ Permutations[{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

A simplification(?) to making `f` work on multiple lists using `f2` and `Fold` is to write a multiple-list shuffle product directly using [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html).

```
f3[in_, out___] :=
 Join @@ ReplaceList[in, {x___, {a_, b___}, y___} :> f3[{x, {b}, y}, out, a]]

f3[{{} ..}, out__] := {{out}}
```

Example:

```
Sort @ f3 @ Gather @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2} === Sort @ Permutations @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

`f3` is not nearly as efficient as `perms` however,

```
x = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5};

perms[x]       // Length // RepeatedTiming
f3[Gather @ x] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.131, 37800}
>
> {1.03, 37800}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not quite as direct:

```
Clear[pnreptwice]
pnreptwice[list_List, {n_}] :=
 Module[{tally},
   tally = SortBy[First]@Tally[list];
   DeleteDuplicates@Select[Tuples[list, n], SortBy[First]@Tally[#] == tally &]
 ]

pnreptwice[{a, b, c, c}, {4}] == Permutations[{a, b, c, c}, {4}]
(* Out: True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Counts`](http://%22http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html%22) with `Select` and [`KeySort`](http://%22http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeySort.html%22) is one possibility, albeit a clunky one.

```
Select[Tuples[{a, b, c}, 4],
  KeySort@Counts@# == <|a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 2|> &] === Permutations[{a, b, c, c}]
(* True *)
```